# Services requires field username on login while using Email Registration Module

Tags: email, drupal, authentication, drupal-7

this is my situation.

version:

- Drupal 7

modules:

- [Email registration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration)
- [realname module](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname)
- [Services Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services)
- ...

When I use my browser, I can login using my email and password.
When I try to log in using services, I need to login using my username instead of my email address.

Here is an example.
1) Register my user (Works fine)
[image: Register my user]

2) User data. As you can see the display name is generated by the Email registration module
[image: Created user Info]

3) Log in using the login-block is succesfull with the email and password
[image: Login using login form]

4) Can't login using service
[image: Login not succesfull]

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Email Registration (Services)](https://www.drupal.org/project/er_svc) module